# How can I create a Wither Storm (from Minecraft Story Mode) in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanted to create the Wither Storm from Minecraft Story Mode.

How would I create a Wither Storm in Minecraft? Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know what that's supposed to be, but it's certainly not anything that exists in Minecraft. Is that a nickname for some kind of machine?

Comment: @FabianRöling [It's a souped-up boss in Story Mode](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Wither_Storm)

Comment: Welcome! When you ask a question, be sure to try to include some background information too to help you get more accurate answers. Try looking at this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some more info.

Comment: @JonK In that case it's not even the same game as the tag says. And that's a "decision based game", right? Then there would be no way to create anything in in.

Comment: @FabianRöling From what I understand, I think that the OP wants to re-create the Story Mods' Wither Storm in classic Minecraft. But anyway, need more clarifications and information in question.

Answer (score 4):

The Wither Storm is not present in any normal edition of Minecraft. It was created entirely for the purpose of Minecraft: Story Mode, and was never intended to appear in the original game.

As it stands, there is no way to summon a Wither Storm without the use of unofficial mods, such as the one Robbie mentioned in his answer.

Note that these mods may require installing an unofficial version of Minecraft, and they may only work in a certain version of the game. For instance, the mod that Robbie linked to requires the Forge mod loader, and it will only work in version 1.8.9, which has been obsolete since 2016.

I would advise that you take caution when installing mods into Minecraft, especially when you are using older versions.