# How do I spawn a Wither Storm (from Minecraft: Story Mode) in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends and I like playing multiplayer and we are looking for a challenge like the Wither Storm but we don't know how to spawn it. How do I spawn a Wither Storm?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Wither Storm (from Minecraft Story Mode) in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/361571/how-can-i-create-a-wither-storm-from-minecraft-story-mode-in-minecraft)

Comment: @OKprogrammer You seem to have flagged to close this question as a dupe of another closed question (which was closed as 'needs details or clarity'). Since this one doesn't seem to be unclear, I voted to leave this question open.

Comment: @galacticninja Ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

[Wither Storm](https://minecraftstorymode.fandom.com/wiki/Wither_Storm) is a boss that only appeared in [Minecraft: Story Mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft:_Story_Mode). As such, it is unavailable in vanilla Minecraft without the use of mods. To quote the Story Mode wiki:

> The Wither Storm cannot be built in normal Minecraft, though all of the materials needed to build one exist.